Can we always find a martingale part in a càdlàg supermartingale?
Abstract: By Doob-Meyer decomposition theorem, for any càdlàg supermartingale $Z$, there exists a unique predictable increasing process $A$ starts from $A_0=0$ such that $Z+A$ is a local martingale starts from $Z_0$. (for example, Protter (2005) Theorem 16 page 116, Dellacherie and Meyer (1982) Theorem 12 page 198).
If removing the condition for $A$ to be predictable, can we always find a martingale $M'$ (not a local martingale) such that $Z=Z_0+M'-A$?
Backgrounds: In the Corollary 4.5 (page 19) of the lecture note by Martin Hairer, the following claim is presented:

Let $\{X_t\}$ be a continuous-time Markov process with càdlàg paths on a Polish space $E$ and let $F,G:[0,\infty)\times E\to\mathbb{R}$ be continuous functions such that
$$
F(t,X_t)-\int_0^tG(s,X_s)\,ds
$$
is a suparmartingale for any starting point $x_0\in E$. Then, if $\Phi\in C^{1,2}([0,\infty)\times\mathbb{R})$ is $C^1$ in its first argument and $C^2$, concave, and increasing in its second argument, we have that
$$
\Phi(t,F(t,X_t))-\int_0^t\biggl(\partial_t\Phi(s,F(s,X_s))+\partial_x\Phi(F(s,X_s))G(s,X_s)\biggr)ds
$$
is a suparmartingale.

The proof starts by claiming that, setting $Y_t:=F(t,X_t)$, there are a càdlàg martingale $M$ and a non-increasing process $N$ such that
$$
dY_t=G(t,X_t)dt+dN_t+dM_t.
$$
However, this requires in general that for any càdlàg supermartingale $Z_t:=Y_t-\int^t_0G(s,X_s)ds$, there is a decomposition $Z_t=Z_0+N_t+M_t$ into càdlàg martingale $M$ and non-increasing $N$.
Am I missing any hidden assumption (such as $\{Z_t\}$ is of class (D))? Or, the general assertion is true?
Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Example: If $B_t$ is a 3-dimensional Brownian motion started at some point other than the origin, then $Z_t:=\|B_t\|^{-1}$ is a positive supermartingale and a (continuous) local martingale. The predictable process in the Doob-Meyer decomposition of this $Z$ is $0$.
However, in Hairer's context, it is part of the definition of the generator (see his page 11) that the local martingale in the Doob-Meyer deomposition of $F(t,X_t)$ is a martingale. Notice that $N_t=-\int_0^t [G(s,X_s)-\mathcal LF(s,X_s)]\,ds$.

Thank you for your insights! However, given that in Remark 2.10 (page 11) he warns even though $\mathcal{L}F\le G$ one can have $F\notin\mathcal{D}(\mathcal{L})$, I thought $F\in\mathcal{D}(\mathcal{L})$ was not assumed.

What does "$\mathcal L F$" mean of $F$ isn't in $\mathcal D(\mathcal L)$?

But anyway, thank you again for your insights. I believe I have found a solution that does not rely on the martingale assumption, by utilizing the fact that a local supermartingale bounded from below is a proper supermartingale. Therefore, while the Corollary 4.5 doesn't hold, Theorem 4.1 still remains valid with a slight modification.
